# Trying to implement exe ()

Tags: c, unix

My operating system OpenBSD 6.6.
For testing, I use a simple program that returns argc. The program is linked statically.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
//    printf("%d\n", argc);
//    printf("Hello world!\n");
      return argc;
}

$ objdump -x hello | grep main
0000000000005680 g     F .text  0000000000000010 main
```

The main program loads the hello one by calling mmap and tries to execute int main () using the well-known symbols from the test binary.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include "defines.h"
#include <fcntl.h>

void * RAM;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i = open("disk/hello", O_RDWR);

    if (i == -1)
        errc(errno, errno, "Unable to open file\n");

    RAM = mmap(0, MEMORY_NPAGE * MEM_PAGE_SIZE,
    PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE, i, 0);
    if (RAM == MAP_FAILED) errc(errno, errno, "Unable to map memory\n");

    printf("fd an allocated addres %d %lx\n", i, (long int)RAM);

    // _Jv_RegisterClasses symbol

    long unsigned int * _Jv_RegisterClasses =  RAM;

    *_Jv_RegisterClasses = (long unsigned int) RAM;


    int (*System)(int, char**) = RAM + 0x5680; //Symbol "T main"

    int j = System(10, argv);

    printf("Hello return %d\n", j);

    if (munmap(RAM, MEMORY_NPAGE * MEM_PAGE_SIZE) == -1)
        errc(errno, errno, "Unable to umap memory\n");


    return 0;
 }
```

Result:

```
fd an allocated addres 3 77f9ad30000
Hello return 10
```

If I start to use something more in hello, errors occur.
What does the _Jv_RegisterClasses symbol mean? What more needs to be done to get Hello World!

Thanks so much for any help.

-1

All these programs are mine, I learn to code. The point is that the hello program contains nothing but instructions, and it is easy to find in memory: call and exit. And easy to call. If I try to inflict a data segment on a child program, I get an error. This is understandable, but I do not know how this is implemented in 64-bit programs.

Hello program build STATICALLY, and have one symbol _Jv_Register_Classes.

OpenBSD 6.6 64 bit... I do not understand how the operating system does it.

Comment: So the wrapper program is not your own, then?  Otherwise, how could you not know what the significance and intended use of one its variables is?  Have you inquired of the code's author / owner about that?

Comment: Having received an `argc` argument of 10, the `main()` function of the hello program is entitled to assume that argv points to an array of at least 11 `char *, with the last being a null pointer.  That's unlikely to be an issue when the function does not actually access `argv`, but you really ought to take care to do these things properly.

Comment: Note also that a program is permitted to modify the array to which `argv` points, and some do.  If your wrapper program doesn't want its own `argv` modified by the hello program, then the former should make a (deep) copy of `argv` (or a completely independent array) to pass to the latter.

Comment: How is the hello program built?  Unless it is statically linked, it seems unlikely that this approach to running it would be viable at all.  Which executable format is it?  If ELF, at least, then `dlopen()` and `dlsym()` provide a standard, pre-built mechanism for doing what your code is doing manually, and they handle dynamically-linked objects to boot.

Comment: You've posted the amendments as *answers*. You should instead [edit]  your question and make the changes in there

Comment: Hello program build STATICALLY, and have one symbol _Jv_Register_Classes.

Comment: All these programs are mine, I learn to code. The point is that the hello program contains nothing but instructions, and it is easy to find in memory: call and exit. And easy to call. If I try to inflict a data segment on a child program, I get an error. This is understandable, but I do not know how this is implemented in 64-bit programs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Linux, but I do know from experience on Windows that simply loading the executable into memory is not enough to call the entry point.

You have to resolve the imports, relocate the image, etc and then call the entry point of the executable file. Even though your executable is statically linked, it still contains imports to systems calls like `SYS_open` and `SYS_write.`

I would suggest learning how the Linux kernel loads and executable image, and how a user-mode program can do it itself, so that the image is properly loaded and can execute without any exceptions.

Comment: It seems to me that syscalls are enough for a static program, and they are available, and the correct value of cpu address registers (for example, for 32-bit mode). SYS write is syscall, I don’t know how windows work.

Answer (score 0):

> If I try to inflict a data segment on a child program, I get an error. This is understandable, but I do not know how this is implemented in 64-bit programs.

It is implemented in 64-bit programs in the same way as in 32-bit programs - the operating system allocates the data segment when a program is loaded. Your *main program* doesn't do that, and since the executable which is mapped into memory doesn't contain the space for the (uninitialized) data, it is inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

Having completed all elf relocations, the result is achieved.